# Problem in using this keyword when declaring variable with let and var

Tags: javascript, scope, this, var, let

The problem here is that when `z` is invoked it prints `undefined`. But when I change the declaration of variable `x` with `var x`, instead of `let x`, it prints `10`. So, what is the difference when using 'this' keyword with `var` and `let` in this code.

```js
let x = 10;
let y = {
  x: 90,
  getX: function() {
    return this.x;
  }
}

console.log(y.getX()); // 90
let z = y.getX;
console.log(z()); // undefined
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#scoping_rules

Comment: @boxdox Unlike var, let doesn't create a property on a global object. That's why we can't use this. Right ??